# How do I troubleshoot ValueError: array is of length %s, while the length of the DataFrame is %s?

Tags: python, dataframe, valueerror, vaex

I'm trying to follow the example on this [notebook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/vaexio/vaex-examples/blob/master/medium-airline-data-eda/airline-original-data-conversion.ipynb).

As suggested in this [github thread](https://github.com/vaexio/vaex/issues/355):

1. I've upped the ulimit to 9999.
2. I've already converted the csv files to hdf5

My code fails when trying to open a single hdf5 file into a dataframe:

```
df = vaex.open('data/chat_history_00.hdf5')
```

Here's the rest of the code:

```
import re
import glob
import vaex
import numpy as np

def tryint(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except:
        return s

def alphanum_key(s):
    """ Turn a string into a list of string and number chunks.
        "z23a" -> ["z", 23, "a"]
    """
    return [ tryint(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', s) ]

hdf5_list = glob.glob('data/*.hdf5')
hdf5_list.sort(key=alphanum_key)
hdf5_list = np.array(hdf5_list)

assert len(hdf5_list) == 11, "Incorrect number of files"

# Check how the single file looks like:
df = vaex.open('data/chat_history_10.hdf5')
df
```

Error generated:

> ERROR:MainThread:vaex:error opening 'data/chat_history_00.hdf5'
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         1 # Check how the single file looks like:
>   ----> 2 df = vaex.open('data/chat_history_10.hdf5')
>         3 df
>
> /usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/**init**.py in
>   open(path, convert, shuffle, copy_index, *args, **kwargs)
>       207                         ds = from_csv(path, copy_index=copy_index, **kwargs)
>       208                     else:
>   --> 209                         ds = vaex.file.open(path, *args, **kwargs)
>       210                     if convert and ds:
>       211                         ds.export_hdf5(filename_hdf5, shuffle=shuffle)
>
> /usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/file/**init**.py
>   in open(path, *args, **kwargs)
>        39             break
>        40     if dataset_class:
>   ---> 41         dataset = dataset_class(path, *args, **kwargs)
>        42         return dataset
>        43
>
> /usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/hdf5/dataset.py
>   in **init**(self, filename, write)
>        84         self.h5table_root_name = None
>        85         self._version = 1
>   ---> 86         self._load()
>        87 
>        88     def write_meta(self):
>
> /usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/hdf5/dataset.py
>   in _load(self)
>       182     def _load(self):
>       183         if "data" in self.h5file:
>   --> 184             self._load_columns(self.h5file["/data"])
>       185             self.h5table_root_name = "/data"
>       186         if "table" in self.h5file:
>
> /usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/hdf5/dataset.py
>   in _load_columns(self, h5data, first)
>       348                                 self.add_column(column_name, self._map_hdf5_array(data, column['mask']))
>       349                             else:
>   --> 350                                 self.add_column(column_name, self._map_hdf5_array(data))
>       351                         else:
>       352                             transposed = shape[1](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/vaexio/vaex-examples/blob/master/medium-airline-data-eda/airline-original-data-conversion.ipynb) < shape[0]
>
> /usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/dataframe.py in
>   add_column(self, name, f_or_array, dtype)    2929
>   if len(self) == len(ar):    2930                         raise
>   ValueError("Array is of length %s, while the length of the DataFrame
>   is %s due to the filtering, the (unfiltered) length is %s." %
>   (len(ar), len(self), self.length_unfiltered()))
>   -> 2931                 raise ValueError("array is of length %s, while the length of the DataFrame is %s" % (len(ar),
>   self.length_original()))    2932             # assert
>   self.length_unfiltered() == len(data), "columns should be of equal
>   length, length should be %d, while it is %d" % (
>   self.length_unfiltered(), len(data))    2933             valid_name =
>   vaex.utils.find_valid_name(name)
>
> ValueError: array is of length 2578961, while the length of the
>   DataFrame is 6

What does this mean and how do I troubleshoot it? All the files has 6 columns.

***EDIT:
Here's how I created the hdf5 file:***

```
pd.read_csv(r'G:/path/to/file/data/chat_history-00.csv').to_hdf(r'data/chat_history_00.hdf5', key='data')
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! We ask that you provide a [mcve] in the text of your question, not as a picture or link to code elsewhere. Also, please [edit] to include the full error traceback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question has been answered by [Jovan](https://github.com/JovanVeljanoski) of [vaex](https://github.com/vaexio) on [Github](https://github.com/vaexio/vaex/issues/554):

> You should not use pandas .to_hdf if you want to read the data with
>   vaex in a memory-mapped way. Please [see this link](https://vaex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#Why-can't-I-open-a-HDF5-file-that-was-exported-from-a-pandas-DataFrame-via-the-.to_hdf?) for more details.

I used this instead:

```
vdf = vaex.from_pandas(df, copy_index=False)
vdf.export_hdf5('chat_history_00.hdf5')
```